# PDO json_encode in ternary operator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am checking if the users information is in the database using

```
$usernameQuery->rowCount();
```

but, I am also putting this code in a ternary operator and echoing the result, which is "*false if its there and true if its not*",  in json but its not working. I researched it and the information i found didn't help and doesn't have the ternary operator. Here is the code

PHP

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    //if email and username is empty then do this
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($username)){

        //Connect to database
        try{

        // new php data object
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

    }

        //find email and username and Prepare
        $emailQuery = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE email = ?");
        $usernameQuery = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE username = ?");

        //Execute;
        $emailQuery->execute(array($email));
        $usernameQuery->execute(array($username));

        //Check if the email is empty
        if(!empty($email)){

            echo "Test";
        }else{

            $nullResult = array();
            $nullResult['Email'] = (!empty($email))? "empty" : "";
            $nullResult['Username'] = ($usernameQuery->rowCount())? false: true;
            echo json_encode($nullResult);
            die("");
        }

    }else{

        $nullResult = array();
        $nullResult['Email'] = (empty($email))? "empty" : "";
        $nullResult['Username'] = (empty($username))? "empty" : "";
        echo json_encode($nullResult);
        exit();

    }



}





?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, i guess you are not checking the condition

```
$count = $usernameQuery->rowCount();

$nullResult['Username'] = (!empty($count)) ? true: false;
```

And After Reading Your Question There is one thing also wrong, you are checking Two Column in Same table With Different Query, i think it should be like this if it's not required to be separate as your requirement

```
$data = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");

$data>execute(array($email,$username));
```

Then Check

```
$nullResult = array();
$nullResult['Email'] = (!empty($data['email'])) ? $data['email'] : 'empty'; 
$nullResult['Username'] = (!empty($data->rowCount()) ? false : true;
```

Here's a solution based on Detail you provided in Question, Hope this helps

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    //if email and username is empty then do this
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($username)){

        //Connect to database
        try{

        // new php data object
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

    }

        //find email and username and Prepare
        $dataQuery = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");

        //Execute;
        $dataQuery->execute(array($email,$user));

        $count = $dataQuery->rowCount()
        //Check if the email is empty
        if(!empty($count)){
                echo "Test";
        }else{

            $nullResult = array();
            $nullResult['Email'] = (!empty($data['email'])) ? $data['email'] : 'empty'; 
            $nullResult['Username'] = (!empty($data->rowCount()) ? false : true;
            echo json_encode($nullResult);
            die("");
        }

    }else{

        $nullResult = array();
        $nullResult['Email'] = (empty($data['email']))? "empty" : "";
        $nullResult['Username'] = (empty($data['username']))? "empty" : "";
        echo json_encode($nullResult);
        exit();

    }



}
```

Comment: I am still getting an empty ""

Comment: empty in where ? in $nullResult['Username'] ?

Comment: Yes, its suppose to be like {"Email":"empty","Username":" false"}

Comment: I got an error and fixed i and now i am getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp64\www\MT\pdovalidation.php on line 38

Comment: I am not sure why you added (!empty($data->rowCount()) because i am checking if the users information is in the data base but not the error.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it by changing up some stuff. The problem was the if and else statements and i had "If the email and password was NOT empty" then run the code. But i was checking in the if and else statement if the username was good and email was empty, so the first part went false and run the button code. Here is the code

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    //if email and username is empty then do this
    if(empty($email) && empty($username)){
         $nullResult = array();
        $nullResult['Email'] = (empty($email))? "empty" : "";
        $nullResult['Username'] = (empty($username))? "empty" : "";
        echo json_encode($nullResult);
        exit();
    }

        //Connect to database
        try{

        // new php data object
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicsever', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

    }

        //find email and username and Prepare
        $emailQuery = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE email = ?");
        $usernameQuery = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM app_signup WHERE username = ?");

        //Execute;
        $emailQuery->execute(array($email));
        $usernameQuery->execute(array($username));

        //Check if the email is empty
        if(empty($email)){

            $nullResult = array();
            $nullResult['Email'] = (!empty($email))? "empty" : "";
            $nullResult['Username'] = ($usernameQuery->rowCount())? false: true;
            echo json_encode($nullResult);
            die("");

        }else{

            echo "Test";
        }



}





?>
```